# How can I corrupt a Git repository?

Tags: git, corruption, corrupt

What are some ways to create a corrupt git repository? Are there ways to permanently damage a git repository interestingly? Can you cripple a git repository such that it behaves somewhat normally but does strange things?

My interest comes from when someone is worried about if they've truly created an unrecoverable state. It usually turns out to be something easy to fix or at least to piece together. Are there hidden (*evil*) gems in git?

Comment: Pick 100 random 8-bit numbers. Xor one of them randomly with every byte in every file in `.git`. Forget the random numbers.

Comment: I mildly seem to recall running into issues with a Git repository that I put into a Dropbox folder - the race conditions as Git tried to write into a file that Dropbox was currently uploading. Not sure what the nature of them was, whether it was a nonobvious corruption or just failed commits, but you might look into it.

Comment: Step one: don't use ECC memory.  Step two: ???.  http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg37928.html

Comment: @ta.speot.is - As amusing as encrypting everything in `.git` sounds, it's rather lackluster. Just did it, and all `git status` reports back is `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`, which is the same as running `status` in any other directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the most straightforward corruption that can happen is the loss of data or data integrity inside the `.git/objects` directory. Since it's designed to be an immutable, write-only storage mechanism, once you violate that assumption, lots of other things will fall apart. Most commonly this would be caused by packfiles that were corrupted in network transmission, say. Unless you're very (read: astronomically) unlucky, though, git will detect this as a matter of course and complain loudly. To get a silent failure this way, you'd need to corrupt a blob in such a way that it preserves its SHA1 hash... under deflate compression... with an accurate type-and-size header.

So, git is pretty good at verifying its own data integrity. What else can we do? To really make state *unrecoverable*, you need:

1. The commits and other objects associated with that state to be unreferenced (that is, not reachable by any named ref under `.git/refs` or any reflog); then
2. Garbage collection to actually delete the state forever, or to take a fresh clone and delete the original.

Otherwise, you'll always be able to run `git checkout <sha> && git branch recovered` and get all of your work back, no matter whatever else you've done. Commits are orphaned like this during normal git usage when you rebase, cherry-pick, or filter-branch, all of which create new commit objects based on the old ones, or if you `git reset --hard` a branch around. By default you have a grace period of [about two weeks](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-gc-and-pruning-this.html) before they get deleted, then, although you can always truncate your reflog and prune manually to nuke something early.

Far more often, I've seen data loss when users never add their data to git in the first place. New users are sometimes hesitant to commit frequently, and attempt to use commands with a dirty working copy, for example. If you never record a state in git, git can't bring it back for you!

If you're okay with *recoverable* but *hard-to-notice* chicanery, you can do some evilness with [git replace](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html) or [graft points](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) to fool git into operating on a fake history with merges or filter-branch operations. Replaced commits still count as reachable, though, so it won't be permanent damage.

Comment: *New users are sometimes hesitant to commit frequently* I keep telling people that commits are free.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: It's a hard mental adjustment to make! I generally try to present it as git having two separate actions: "commit" for recording state, and "push" for sharing state. Even when people understand it rationally, though, habits are the hardest things to change.